# Multivariate nonparametric divergence (or distance) between distributions

Tags: distributions, multivariate-analysis, distance-functions

For example, we could say I have two fruit classes (oranges and apples) and for each one I measured different statistics of interest, for example: width, height, sugar, water... of a lot of fruit units. Therefore, for each of the statistics I have a probability distribution based on the, let's say, 100,000 different fruits measured.

```
           Width    Height  Sugar
Apple       X1       Y1      Z1
Orange      X2       Y2      Z2
```

In this case, the distributions are probably normal distributed, but in my case they are not. I don't know the type of distribution.

I would like to compare them in order to see «how similar» they are. I searched and I found a lot of tests for checking the divergence (or distance) between distributions (Kullback-Leibler, Kolmogorov-Smirnov, Hellinger, Jensen-Shannon...). The problem is that with them I can only compare two distributions (for example apple and orange width). It would be better to take all the statistics of interest together for the comparison.

Therefore, I would like to know a Multivariate nonparametric technique for comparing the divergences/distances between the distributions that gives a number. For example, DIST(X1,Y1,Z1 | X2,Y2,Z2) = value between [0,1], meaning that there is no divergence or there is a lot, respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-response Permutation Procedures (MRPP) is one possibility, with the two groups being apples and oranges. Note that both the degree of overlap and overall within-group variation matter for the final difference between groups, so it is possible to have two groups that overlap completely be different if they differ in within-group distance. So best to use an ordination technique such as NMDS to visualize the results. Significance value is obtained via permutation.

Check the documentation of this R [package](https://rdrr.io/rforge/vegan/man/mrpp.html).

Comment: I have added the latest active site. Check your post after the edit when you visit again here.